# C# dataGridView doesn't return correct cell value under Windows XP when perform fast cell click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winform application that uses dataGridView. What I want to do is that when user clicks on the cell, it display the cell content to the textbox. Here is the code that I handle the click event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {                
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            textBox1.Text = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        }            

    }
```

Everything works fine in Windows 7. However, when I run it under Windows XP, there is an issue.

I will explain this issue with a simple example.I add some data to the dataGridView with a button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("John","123");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Rob","456");            
    }
```

So, if you click first row, textbox will display "John"; if you click second row, it will be "Rob". This works fine under Windows 7 and if you perform click with some delay(like 1 second), it also work fine under Windows XP. However, if you perform fast click, like 5~6 time within one second between first and second row, a lot of time, the textbox's will display "Rob" even you click first row, or other way around. It just doesn't display the correct data according to its row.

I have try putting enable disable dataGridView / refresh dataGridView between each click, none of them work. The only thing works that is delaying the mouse click: move cursor position or show a messagebox after clicking, they are just work around, but not a real solution.

Have any one experience this before? Is this a Windows XP "bug"? By the way, my develop environment is Window 7 with VS2010. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: How you delay mouse click? Maybe You can use sleep? System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) will delay 1 second, but from other hand that can be slow...And i am not sure that is real solution to

Comment: After mouse click, I show a message box to delay the click on cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

I was using Cell Click event to handle selection, it should work, but not sure why it doesn't work under Windows XP.

`private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)'
with handle
'this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);`

Then I change the way of selection to selectionchange, it works fine in both Windows 7 & XP.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

this.dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check before you perform the task.  Try something like this:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex == e.RowIndex)
{
     DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
     textBox1.Text = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
}
```